# Compute times in Java eg. 1900-1710 = 110 mins

Tags: java, time, date-arithmetic

is there any way in java to do that? I want it to compute the times like that. 0950-0900 is 50 mins but 1700-1610 = 50 mins instead of 90, 1900-1710 = 110 instead of 190. thanks :)

Comment: And what is 0010 - 0020? should it be 2350?

Comment: Sure - I'd use Joda Time, personally - is that an option for you?

Comment: Also, if using Java8, you can use the new date and time features based on Joda Time.

Comment: @amit yeah but I don't need it right now because I am just trying to find the mean length of time and I'm not having it going back like that.

Comment: @Jon Skeet no sorry Joda Time is not an option for me, I was just looking for like a method or some mathematical calculation that I'm missing to do this, Thanks for the input though :)

Comment: So what form is your input? Integers? Or text? Your question isn't terribly clear.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hey sorry, my input is intergers.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) (part of the new [Date & Time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) introduced in Java SE 8).

Eg. (untested):

```
long minutes = Duration.between(toLocalTime(1710), toLocalTime(1900)).toMinutes();

private LocalTime toLocalTime(int time){
  return LocalTime.of(time / 100, time % 100);
}
```

Comment: Or, equivalently, `ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(LocalTime.of(17,10), LocalTime.of(19,00))`

Comment: Why is there no option to save answers? This one is really straight forward.

Comment: @Puce hey thanks but its says that cannot find symbol - variable Localime?

Comment: @Puce you might want to add that this requires java 8

Comment: @NandaArdianto Make sure you're using Java SE 8 (Oracle Java SE 7 reaches EoL this month) and make sure you're using "LocalTime" not "Localime".

Comment: @Puce haha typo on the LocalTime there, I will try that, but is there another way? Like my times are intergers, so int 1900 int 1700 etc and would I use it the same way?

Comment: @NandaArdianto: See my answer - but it's horrible to represent compound values like that.

Comment: @NandaArdianto I incorporated part of Jon Skeet's answer to convert integers to LocalTime.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new Java Date API from Java 8.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("19:00");
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse("17:10");
Duration elapsed = Duration.between(start, end);
System.out.println(elapsed.toMinutes());
```

This will output: -110 and 110 if you switch start and end.

Answer (score 2):

If you've just got integers, and you don't care about validation, you *can* do it all without touching time parts at all:

```
public int getMinutesBetween(int time1, int time2) {
    // Extract hours and minutes from compound values, which are base-100,
    // effectively.
    int hours1 = time1 / 100;
    int hours2 = time2 / 100;
    int minutes1 = time1 % 100;
    int minutes2 = time2 % 100;
    // Now we can perform the arithmetic based on 60-minute hours as normal.
    return (hours2 - hours1) * 60 + (minutes2 - minutes1);
}
```

However, I'd *strongly* recommend that you use more appropriate representations - these *aren't* just normal `int` values... they're effectively "time of day" values, so `LocalTime` (in either Joda Time or Java 8's `java.time`) is the most appropriate representation, IMO.

Comment: if 1700 is 17:00 shouldn't you divide by 100?